# Can't override only template on custom module (uppercase problem)

Tags: magento2, module, layout, template, overrides

The problem is I have the vendor name capitalized, and then, don't know why the overrides don't work. Only when you want to change the template but still using default block. For example:

Override the `catalog_product_view` (single product page - the image)

Folders structure:

```
app\code\GST
└───Override
    │   registration.php
    │
    ├───etc
    │       module.xml
    │
    └───view
        └───frontend
            ├───layout
            │       catalog_product_view.xml
            │
            └───templates
                └───product
                    └───view
                            gallery.phtml
```

`registration.php`

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'GST_Override',
__DIR__
);
```

`module.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="GST_Override" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

`catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.media.image" template="GST_Override::product/view/gallery.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

`gallery.phtml`

```
<p> test </p>
```

Expected result: No image shown and display 'test'

Actual result: Default magento view

**What I've tried:**

1) If I use remove attribute on layout:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.media.image" template="GST_Override::product/view/gallery.phtml" remove="true"/>
```

**The image is removed.**

2) If I use custom block on layout:

```
<referenceBlock class="GST\Override\Block\Product\View\Gallery" name="product.info.media.image" template="GST_Override::product/view/gallery.phtml" remove="true"/>
```

**It works.**

3) Definately, if I use a 'normal' vendor name like Test **it works.**

Is this a kind of bug? should I never use all capital leters to name vendor or module? Did I make a mistake? Can you reproduce this error or it's just me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capitalizing vendor name is not a problem. But for our own convenience we will be using first letter as capital.

Comment: Yep, but now I have made enough modules with this namespacing. And the thing is, I have some overrides like this that aren't working, I'd need to create another vendor or something else bc I cannot solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem not in module name and in module load sequence.

Try add to `module.xml`

```
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        <module name="Magento_ProductVideo"/>
    </sequence>
```

Comment: Tried, doesn't work.